# Flutter implementing socket.io with dart

Tags: websocket, socket.io, dart, flutter

i am trying to implement socket.io with my flutter app, currently flutter is supporting WebSocket but i have found a way for socket.io in package "dart.io" but i am unable to understand how to emit a message on a specific event. Any suggestions would be helpful :)

Comment: Perhaps https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_socket_io

Comment: Thanks for this GünterZöchbauer :)  i think you are right, will test it soon.

Comment: i have tested this plugin but it is unable to connect, My native android side is working find. createSocketIO() has 4 parameters, i have input the domain, have no namespace so i tried empty string and null also but no success in sending the message. Logcat shows the isConnected:false.
Need help on this one.

Comment: I think you can read in the [documetation](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets) about websockets first, [flutter socket.io](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/socket_io) and [flutter socket.io client](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/socket_io_client) too

Comment: Hello @rize thanks for the answer, i tried flutter socket.io client. Just by calling the 
`IO.Socket socket = IO.io(SOCKET_URL);
    socket.connect();`
then i get an error of

Comment: Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
    'package:socket_io_client/src/engine/socket.dart': error: line 83 pos 38: file:///C:/Flutter/SDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/socket_io_client-0.9.0+1/lib/src/engine/socket.dart:83:38: Error: The getter 'window' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::Socket'.
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'window'.

Answer (score 3):

I have ported socket.io in dart code since 2017, and it can work with flutter as well in the same codebase - [socket.io-client-dart](https://github.com/rikulo/socket.io-client-dart) and [socket.io-dart](https://github.com/rikulo/socket.io-dart).

Answer (score 1):

Using this [flutter_socket_io](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_socket_io) package, I managed to connect to my local Socket IO server.

```
SocketIO socket = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO("http://localhost:3000", "/");
socket.init();
socket.connect();
```

Maybe you could share your implementation on both client and server side to debug further.

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for this [flutter_socket_io](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_socket_io)

Comment: check my last comment to Günter Zöchbauer. "i have tested this plugin but it is unable to connect, My native android side is working fine. createSocketIO() has 4 parameters, i have input the domain, have no namespace so i tried empty string and null but no success in sending the message. Logcat shows the isConnected:false. Need help on this one"

Comment: use "/" in namespace parameter as default namespace in socket io

Comment: namespace as you said but still the socket status is interchanging from "reconnecting" to "disconnect"
socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO(SOCKET_URL, "/", socketStatusCallback: _socketStatus);
socketIO.init();
    socketIO.connect();

Comment: i am pretty sure thats not the issue, internet permission is also in the android manifest.